# SSH config for connecting to host via reverse SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, configuration, ssh-tunneling, ssh-config, visual-studio-code

I set up a reverse SSH tunnel to access a node, `node1`, behind a NAT. I have set up an EC2 instance, `myEC2`, to act as the intermediary. From my `laptop`, when I want to access `node1`, I have to SSH into the EC2 in order to then SSH into the node.

**The workflow is like this:**

1. In `node1`, make sure to run: `ssh -i key.pem -R 3000:localhost:22 ubuntu@myEC2`. This is always running in a service.
2. From my `laptop`, SSH into the EC2: `ssh ubuntu@myEC2`
3. Once inside the EC2: `ssh xavier@localhost -p 3000`
4. I'm in `node1`!

**What I'm looking for is a way of expressing that workflow in a SSH config that I can use to login directly into `node1` from my `laptop`**. This will help me access `node1` via Visual Studio Code's Remote SSH extension.

I tried something like this:

```
Host node1
Hostname myEC2
User ubuntu
Port 3000
IdentityFile key.pem
```

But that does not work, I assume it is because `Port` should be `22` rather than `3000`. I just really don't know how to express the workflow. I have looked into `ProxyJump` but I'm not sure if that is what I'm looking for and to be honest I haven't had success with that either.

Any suggestions are welcomed! =D

---

**Edit #1:** After following Stéphane's suggestions I ended up with an ssh_config file that looks like this:

```
Host myEC2
Hostname <myEC2_IP>
User ubuntu
Port 22
IdentityFile ec2_key.pem

Host node1
Hostname localhost
User xavier
Port 3000
IdentityFile /path/to/node1-id_rsa
ProxyJump ubuntu@myEC2
```

While I can SSH into `myEC2` with no issues, I can't go into `node1`. My understanding is that this is supposed to be equivalent to `ssh -p 3000 -J ubuntu@myEC2 xavier@localhost`. Any help is greatly appreciated! This is what I get by adding the `-v` flag to SSH.

```
xaviermerino@Xaviers-MBP .ssh % ssh doc
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l ubuntu -W '[localhost]:3000' myEC2
debug1: identity file node1-id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file node1-id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Connecting to myEC2 [myEC2_IP_ADDRESS] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ec2_key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file ec2_key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to myEC2_IP_ADDRESS:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/U4HE+zUBFNZJgxDM6lWDW7FX8GSHXWYc/fMEyOvMlw
debug1: Host 'myEC2_IP_ADDRESS' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xaviermerino/.ssh/known_hosts:226
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: ec2_key.pem  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: ec2_key.pem
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to myEC2 ([IP_Address_Goes_Here]:22).
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd localhost:3000
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I'm not sure what this means Does it have to do with the settings at `sshd_config` in the EC2?. This is what I have in there:

```
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
```

---

**Edit #2**: Someone had turned off the computers. It now works! To summarize it for whoever is looking into this. To solve this, I needed:

```
Host myEC2
Hostname <myEC2_IP>
User ubuntu
Port 22
IdentityFile ec2_key.pem

Host node1
Hostname localhost
User xavier
Port 3000
IdentityFile /path/to/node1-id_rsa
ProxyJump ubuntu@myEC2
```

And that was it! Thanks @StephaneChazelas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually using `myEC2` as a *jump host*.

You could ssh to `node1` from your laptop with:

```
ssh -p 3000 -J ubuntu@myEC2 xavier@localhost
```

The corresponding `ssh_config` entries would look like:

```
Host node1
Hostname localhost
User xavier
Port 3000
IdentityFile key.pem
ProxyJump ubuntu@myEC2
```

Note that the `IdentityFile` there is the one used for authenticating to `node1`. To specify one for `myEC2`, you'd use another `Host` entry for `myEC2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, even after creating another `Host` entry for `myEC2` it is not working. In the `myEC2` entry, I used the `IdentityFile` that corresponds to the EC2. In the `node1` entry, I used the `IdentityFile` that corresponds to `node1`. Any ideas? I updated the question to reflect this. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @XavierMerino you missed the ProxyJump line. Does it work with `-J`? You can also add a few `-v` options if it's still not working which may give a clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: thanks! I was missing that line! However it still doesn't work. It mentions a `bad file descriptor` when, I assume, it tries to redirect input. Any ideas? Can it be something related to the `sshd_config` in the EC2? I edited to question to include the output of the verbose `-v` flag.

Comment: @XavierMerino, it's the kind of verbose output you'd get if there was nothing listening on port 3000 on EC2. Are you sure the remote port forward is started and operational there?

Comment: sorry. It's quite an embarrassing thing. The computers were turned off. But now it works! Thank you so much! =D